# How to install GDAL extension for GeoServer on Windows

Tags: geoserver, gdal, windows

I am in search of guidance to set up the GDAL extension for GeoServer.

I used GeoServer 2.11.0 with the geoserver-2.11.0-gdal-plugin.zip files, folowing the guide from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html but gets errors running it.

```
Welcome to GeoServer!

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121

Please wait while loading GeoServer...

WARNING: Module not found [ssl]
2017-04-27 09:24:30.623:INFO::main: Logging initialized @565ms
2017-04-27 09:24:30.770:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
2017-04-27 09:24:30.793:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/C:/Data/geoserver-2.11.0/webapps/] at interval 1
2017-04-27 09:24:31.885:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2017-04-27 09:24:32.755:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1be98f5{/geoserver,file:/C:/Data/geoserver-2.11.0/webapps/geoserver/,STARTING}{C:\Data\geoserver-2.11.0\webapps\geoserver}: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.arcbinarygrid.ArcBinaryGridImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.arcbinarygrid.ArcBinaryGridImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

The system is:

```
Win 7 64bit

MSVC 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 2015 is installed in both 64 and 32 bit

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I installed the 32bit dlls and ECW driver:

gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010.zip

gdal-19-1600-ecw.msi

For full error log see https://pastebin.com/ret8qZhi

Comment: is that 64 or 32 bit Java? I think it needs to be 32 bit

Comment: I think it is 32 bit. Running `java -d64 -version` in CMD returns `Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM`

Comment: @iant Using imageio-ext releases/1.1.15 it works, but only never versions supports VRT which I need.

Comment: then you will need to make new swig bindings and (probably) rework the java code in GeoTools to make use of the new features

Answer (score 1):

I could make GDAL-ImageI/O-Ext extension work in GeoServer 2.14.1 on Windows just in ONE way: using Apache Tomcat 8.5 and installing GeoServer as a WAR.
Using the Windows installer adds one more layer to the stack: the wrapper.
This [has proved](https://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/fix-gdal-extension-not-working-with-geoservers-windows-service-wrapper/) to be a source of further troubles that can mix with all other ones making the deployment very triky.

My recipe is the following:

Make sure you have MSVC 2010 64bit installed. Is a a requirement of the GDAL native libraries.

[Install Tomcat 8.5 64bit](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.37/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.37.exe) ona a 64bit JDK (I tested with 1.8.202). DO NOT GO WITH A 32bit JDK/JRE!

Use “Configure Tomcat” link in Start Menu to increase assigned RAM to 2048Mb

Copy Geoserver 2.14.1 WAR in `[TomcatInstallDir]\webapps` : this will make Tomcat self-deploy (unpack) the WAR into a `/geoserver` sub-dir and serve it on URL http://localhost:8080/geoserver (..or whatever port you choose during installation)

Uzip [gdal-data.zip](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/gdal-data.zip) in `C:/gdal/gdal-data`

Unzip native libs GDAL from [gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010-x64.zip](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2010/gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010-x64.zip) in `C:/gdal/`

Unzip GDAL Extension plugin for your Geoserver version (mine was 2.14.1) from 
http://geoserver.org/release/2.14.1/ into `[TomcatInstallDir]\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib`

Optional for JP2 / ECW support
Unzip “driver” native libs forer JP2/ECW from [gdal-19-1600-x64-ecw.msi (ECW lib)](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2010/gdal-19-1600-x64-ecw.msi) in `C:/gdal/`

Add to PATH env var:
`C:/gdal`

Configure in Windows the following Environment variables:
`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\gdal`
`GDAL_DATA = C:\gdal\gdal-data`
`GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR = [TomcatInstallDir]\webapps\geoserver\data`

The latter `\data` dir can be moved from the default out-of-the box location to a more sensible one. The GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR will have to reflect thischange.

*** * * NOTE: As of Feb 2019 I still do not know a way to use any other, more recent version of GDAL other than v. 1.9.2 in Geoserver on Windows * * ***